Property 'listObjectsV2' does not exist when jest mocking it?
I'm building a jest unit test.
I want to mock the S3 listObjectsV2 using the spyOn function using the following code
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
jest.spyOn<any, any>(S3.prototype, 'listObjectsV2').mockReturnValue({
    promise: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
            $response: {
                Contents: [
                    { Key: 'assets/file1', Size: 5 },
                    { Key: 'assets/file2', Size: 5 },
                    { Key: 'assets/excluded-file2', Size: 5 },
                ],
            },
        }),
});

For some reason I'm getting
Property 'listObjectsV2' does not exist in the provided object runtime error.
Anyone knows why?

What's the version of aws-sdk package?

version aws-sdk 2.1601

listObjectsV2 was introduced in a later version of the AWS SDK (around v3).
Your code (AWS-SDK version: 2.1601) likely uses an older version where listObjectsV2 doesn't exist.
The recommended approach is to upgrade your AWS SDK to a version that supports listObjectsV2. Refer to the AWS SDK for JavaScript documentation for upgrade instructions: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/
Mocking with the Existing Method:
Here's an example mocking with a potential alternative method (listObjects):
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';

jest.spyOn<any, any>(S3.prototype, 'listObjects').mockReturnValue({
    Contents: [
        { Key: 'assets/file1', Size: 5 },
        { Key: 'assets/file2', Size: 5 },
        { Key: 'assets/excluded-file2', Size: 5 },
    ],
});

